# Connection of 3 Models with Foreign Key

Tags: django

I am a newbie in Django. I have 3 models: Continent, Country, Region

Here is the code:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Continent(models.Model):
    continent = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['continent']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.continent

class Country(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['country']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Countries'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country

class Region(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['region']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.region

    def get_continent(self):
        return self.get_continent()
```

my admin.py looks like this:

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from location.models import Continent, Country, Region

    # Register your models here.
    class MyAdmin1(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ['continent']
        #list_display_links = None
        #actions = None 

    class MyAdmin2(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ['country', 'continent']

    class MyAdmin3(admin.ModelAdmin):
        model = Region    
        list_display = ['region', 'country', 'get_continent']


    admin.site.register(Continent, MyAdmin1)
    admin.site.register(Country, MyAdmin2)
    admin.site.register(Region, MyAdmin3)
```

But in admin panel when I click on table regions it doesn't show 3 attributes in 3 columns. Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a infinite recursion in the `Region.get_continent()` method:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_continent(self):
        return self.get_continent()
```

Change it to:

```
    def get_continent(self):
        return self.country.continent
```